# Qt changing window content / General Qt window / dialog

Tags: c++, windows, qt, switch-statement

I have been searching for a while on how do i choose useful widget/windows/dialogs in Qt.

My main idea is to program a game (for my school subject in multimedia).

I need to write this program in Qt, and i have a problem at switching the content of my window usefully.

I have 3 main dialog types: Window, Widget, Dialog. 
Then i found the QGraphicsView which is usable with QGraphicsScene.

I think i would use QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene for animations, but i want to get a menu before, like a mainWindow with some buttons like "Start", "Quit", etc.

**What is an useful construct of window forms?**
**What would be my mainWindow to switch the content? (and how)**

*All examples for Qt i found were just maybe 1 or 2 .cpp + .h files with no window switch*.

---

```
TL;DR:
```

I searching for the right classes to use for such a construct:

```
MainWindow
(Start | Options | End)

If (Start) { goto GameWindow }
If (Options) { goto OptionsWindow }
If (End) { close }
```

The GameWindow should be able to use sounds, animations, keyInput, QGraphicsView etc. (**widget?**)
The MainWindow should be a dialog or a normal window i think.
Options aswell.

I don't know how to switch between these windows, so for example if click on start he loads the GameWindow content in my actual window.

I'm sorry when this question was already asked in the past, i searched a while and i'm still not able to express my question correctly.

thanks for all help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look this for create your Windows transition.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html

Or you can design your application with QML and write your game in C++ with QGraphicsScene.